# Use Angular with an existing Asp.Net Website

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, webforms

I am working on a project where we already have an existing website built using Asp.Net.  We are planning to add some new pages and update some existing one.
I am planning to develop those new pages in Angular 5 with Webpack. We can not convert the whole website into Angular due to budget constraint but ultimate goal is to convert in completely in Angular 5.

Have anyone worked on such a hybrid app in recent future?
Can someone please throw some light on it, whether it is workable and If there is any performance impact due to mixing up the technologies.

Comment: Hi @Akash, do you have any feedback about the migration?

Answer (score 5):

Yes I'm working in a similar situation, and it's definitely possible. An .NET page (MVC?) can return an Angular SPA and take control of the UI flow from that point on.

Say you want to start by creating a "User Profile" page in Angular. When the user navigates to that page in your standard MVC site, it should return the page with the Angular application loaded (as a javascript script reference). From there on, the Angular app can handle further redirects and logic.

It does make some things complicated, but it's usually not feasible to port things in one go. This approach has allowed us to move over to Angular, 1 page at a time.

Comment: Thanks @Carlos Rodriguez.  I am even planning to do in exact same approach i.e. "1 page at a time".  In my case, it is an Website and not an MVC.  
Couple of things-

1) Have you encounter with any performance related issues with this apprach??
2)  Have you created any plunkr OR is there a good article, I can refer to ??

Comment: If you're not careful, there could be performance related issues with all the client-side "fun" you can have in Angular. Javascript change detection can become pretty expensive. But on the whole, no I wouldn't say I've had any performance troubles. I unfortunately don't have any plunkr set up as I don't own this code base though.

Comment: If you're using Webforms (.aspx) then you'd definitely need to set up a separate Web API project as well that would let your Angular app communicate with the backend. Your Web API and your .aspx back end files can share the same business logic. Your .aspx pages should link to the Angular html files to integrate them.

Comment: I see your point. Actually putting an web api layer is perfectly fine and both aspx and angular pages can use them.  One last question,  when you guys started this, did you refer some literature which helped you guys ?  If yes, than I would like to go through those doc as well. Thanks!!

Comment: Carlos Rodriguez :  You used Systemjs OR webpack ?

Comment: I actually was brought onto this project after it's started so I'm not entirely sure if there was any documentation that was used for inspiration. Sorry :-\. But we are using Webpack for the client side stuff

Comment: Carlos Rodriguez: Thank You. I Am working on a POC. I will post the outcome here soon.

Comment: No problem. This is definitely possible. The product I'm working on is already being used by customer's in this "hybrid state" and it's more than manageable.

Answer (score 2):

We at a large company have done exactly that. It is very simple. Using angular-cli create a new project

`ng new my-project`

and copy the contents into the root of your existing ASP.NET solution. You will now need to use

`ng build --watch`

instead of

`ng serve`

and copy the script includes from `/dist/index.html` into your aspx or cshtml file.

Comment: I tried that as per your suggestion but than I am getting below error. If I remove all the angular code than it just works fine.Have you faced such issues. I do have virtual directory created but I am not able to build this project.

`It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.`

Comment: just to clarify, this error is because there are some packages in the node_module directory which has a "web.config" file.  I can not delete this folder other wise angular content will not build. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: I figured it out. Just made the "node_modules" folder hidden and all works.